Is there a computer that loses all data after each restart and if so what is the term to describe such a computer?
I am not a computer scientist (or any kind of scientist) and the following question might be better off posted at RetroComputing SE but it also deals with a theoretical model (probably a bit crappy one but still a theoretical model) so it may fit here the most.
Is there a computer that loses all data after each restart and if so what is the term to describe such a computer?
To delay on the term "restart" a bit, I don't talk about a regular restart or even about the deeper term "reset" with some data being saved but a complete loss of data after any of thse; in such a computer any drive (may it be soft, or hard) is being totally formatted when a session is finished, no data could ever be recovered from such a drive if a restart/reset was done; is there such a computer which is basically just hardware and software (no firmware) that can be reprogrammed each time anew as maybe the first computer in history was?

Maybe are you thinking of a diskless system.

Back in the 80's, the place where I worked had an IMSAI 8080.  They would use the front panel switches to enter in a small boot loader program into memory, then execute the boot loader.  The boot loader would then read in the operating system from a paper tape reader.  That computer was later upgraded with a ROM card that would execute on startup and read the operating system from a floppy drive.

It's any computer without writeable persistent memory. They usually have a ROM where the program is stored.
That is most simple electronics before flash memory became cheap. For example an old school console like the PS2 or older which rely on external memory (either explicit or embedded in the game cartridge) or passwords to allow a player to resume a game where they left off.
However they don't get "reprogrammed" each time they boot up, instead the ROM contains the program they should execute.

ROM is also data.

The question specifies ‘no firmware’, so a ROM-based system is out of scope.
